# Looking for advice on a 12V relay circuit with ESP32

Tags: transistors, relay, design, esp32

I've made the below circuit on a custom PCB and it doesn't appear to work as intended. For whatever reason, I'm seeing only ~3.8-4V on the coil pins of the relay rather than the expected 12V needed to actually  throw them.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

[image: Aforementioned circuit]

Comment: If you're only seeing 4V on the relay coil, where is the rest of the voltage drop? (eg measure from GND to pin1 pin8  and +12V)

Comment: As it turns out, I was simply forgetting to connect the 12V rail! 4V on the relay coil is from the 5V supply somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic looks functional.

Maybe there's an issue with the PCB such as wrong footprint to schematic mapping. If you provide images of the PCB (and preferably a photo of the assembled PCB) we can look more closely.

Or the SS36 are something else (why use 3A Schottky rectifiers for a brief *peak* current of 33mA?). Any silicon rectifier such as LL4148 or M7 will work just as well and will waste less power at high Ta.

Or maybe the 10 ohm resistors are really much higher (there would be voltage drop across them). Or your 12V supply is collapsing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As it turns out, for some reason I can't figure out the particular LEDs I was using was somehow shorting the rest of my circuit, clouding my troubleshooting efforts. My 12V to 5V reg circuit isn't functioning properly either for some reason, have to figure that out and then I'll be back!